# Not understanding pointers in C

Tags: c, pointers

I am apparently misunderstanding the usage of pointers in c. The book says *write a program that will find the largest of two numbers and change the value of those variables to the larger value* and I am doing something wrong. Here is my code, could anyone please help?

```
/*finds the largest of two variables, replaces them with it*/
#include <stdio.h>

void larger_of(double *i, double *j);

int main(void) {
    double i, j;
    printf("Please enter two numbers.\n");
    scanf("%lf %lf", &i, &j);
    printf("i is %lf and j is %lf.\n", i, j);
    larger_of(&i, &j);
    printf("Now i is %lf and j is %lf.\n", i, j);
    printf("DONE\n");

    return 0;
}

void larger_of(double *i, double *j) {
    double *ptr1 = &i;
    double *ptr2 = &j;
    if(i > j) {
        *ptr1 = *i;
        *ptr2 = *i;
    } else {
        *ptr1 = *j;
        *ptr2 = *j;
    }

    return;
}
```

Comment: `if (i > j)` compares pointers, not pointees. You want `if (*i > *j) { *j = *i; } else { *i = *j; }`

Comment: So are you saying that it is currently comparing the actual addresses? Do I even need the two `ptr1` and `ptr2` variables in the last bit?

Comment: Yeah. Sort of. It's in fact undefined behaviour to do this...

Comment: "I am doing something wrong" is not a useful error description. When posting a question about a bug in your code, please describe what visibly goes wrong and what was supposed to happen instead. An [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) is also helpful.

Comment: You should get a compilation error for the line `double *ptr1 = &i;` - don't ignore this

Comment: You've not explained either what the code is supposed to do or the problem with it that's causing you to ask for help here. If you want help here, explain what you're attempting to do, post the code that attempts to do so, and explain the problem that you're having with that code and ask a specific question.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, but I know so little about pointers that...explaining what was wrong would be like explaining quantum aerodynamics to my dog.

@KerrekSB Thanks, that fixed it. Though now I get a gcc warning "initialization from incompatible pointer type". Could you tell me what this means?

Comment: @user3813418: Means it's not fixed

Comment: @MooingDuck Screw it, implemnting the simpler solution Kerrek suggested made those unnecessary variables anyways.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a variable declared as

```
double * d;
```

`d` contains the address of the object that contains the `double` value; `*d` contains `double` value, `&d` is the address of the pointer object `d`.

Now, in your function,

```
double *ptr1 = &i;
```

is not correct.  What you need is `double * ptr1 = i`.  This will put the address of object pointed to by `i` into `ptr1` and you can dereference the object as either `*ptr1` or `*i`.  In the comparison, you need to compare the dereferenced objects as `(*i > *j)`.

Other things seem correct in your code.

Comment: How is i a pointer though? Is it because I called the function with `larger_of(&i,&j)` or what?

Comment: @user3813418: You wrote `double *i`.  That's pretty clear that `i` is a pointer.

Comment: @user3813418 That's exactly why. Yes.

Comment: Alright, thank you for dealing with my stupidity. Pointers have repeatedly made me give up on C, but I'm determined this time.

Answer (score 2):

In `larger_of` you should have *these* two lines:

```
double *ptr1 = i;
double *ptr2 = j;
```

Note the removal of the ampersands ('&'). Having the ampersands there should be wrong because then you are setting `ptr1` and `ptr2` to the *addresses* of `i` and `j`, and so `ptr1` and `ptr2` should be `double**`s, which they are not.

In addition, you need to check if `*i > *j`, not if `i > j`, because you want to compare the values *pointed to* by the pointers, not the pointers themselves (`i > j` compares the addresses pointed to by the pointers).

However, you could make `larger_of` more concise by turning it into the following:

```
void larger_of(double *i, double *j)
{
    if (*i > *j)
        *j = *i;
    else
        *i = *j;
}
```

So if the value pointed to by `i` is greater than that pointed to by `j`, then set the value pointed to by `j` to that pointed to by `i`. Do the opposite for the `else`.

Comment: @MooingDuck I must be tired, because I'm not seeing how it's wrong. Could you please explain?

Comment: @MooingDuck: I agree with Jashaszun, he implemented the specification correctly.  You're reading something into a comment that isn't in the specification (and honestly, isn't in the comment, either).

Comment: @BenVoigt: After rereading the OP code, I realize that Jashaszun's code does the same thing as that, so I take back my complaint.  I was mistaken.